# Form submit button in a DataTable not working in IE 11(due to DataTable bug)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am using `DataTable` in a web application and I find that DataTable is not compatible with inline forms with a `<button type="submit" formaction="..."></button>`. In IE 11 it is not working; submit does not work, but in Chrome 65 and Firefox 59 it is working.

Table is a `DataTable`:

```
$('#dataTable-script').DataTable({
    "scrollX": true,                            /* horizontal scroll */
    "responsive": false,                        /* turn this OFF to enable scrollX. Conflict. */
    "columnDefs": [
        { "visible": true, "targets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] }, /* always show 5 columns */
        { "orderable": false, "targets": [9] }  /* the last column not sortable */
    ],
    "order": [
        [ 6, 'desc' ]                           /* initial ordering */
    ],
    "searching": true,                          /* enable searching/filtering; nothing to do with show/hide search input */
    /* dom elements manipulation */
    /* f: filter(search input); l: combobox of each page size, _T_ble, _I_nformation, _P_agination, p_R_ocessing-element. */
    "dom": "<'row'<'col-md-7 col-lg-9 col-sm-4'l><'col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-5'f>>" + /* 'l' and 'f' on the same line */
           "<'row'<'col-md-12't>>" +             /* table with correct margin */
           "<'row'<'col-md-7 col-lg-9 col-sm-4'i><'col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-5 pull-right'p>>" + /* 'i' and 'p' on the same line */
           "r", 
    "processing": true, /* indicate "processing..." when doing time-consuming task. Related to 'dom':'r': without 'r' it is hidden. */
)};
```

With every line as a form:

```
<tbody>
    {% for script in scripts %}
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="formManager{{script.id}}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type='hidden' name='scriptID' value='{{script.id}}' />
            <td>{{script.name}}</td>
            <td>{{script.category.name}}</td>
            <td>{{script.platform.name}}</td>
            ...
```

And at the end of every line, a button like;

```
<button type="submit" formaction="{% url 'deleteScript' %}"
    onclick="return confirm()"
    class="btn btn-danger btn-circle" title="Delete script">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
</button>
```

I have created a demo in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqgy3ygx/45/), however it shows that with DataTable it does not work even in Chrome neither Firefox, but it is not true; in reality it just stops in IE, only tested IE 11. However, if you delete the DataTable definition, it just works in IE and other modern web explorers, which is the same with my real code.

I have searched and find ppl talking about `DataTables` ordering, even disabled, will delete some attributes and stop IE from working, but Chrome and FireFox can work without it.

Comment: Make the button a standard button and on click, build up the `data` yourself before sending it to the target url using ajax.

Comment: But then I should do the redirect myself.. I have some "Edit Script" and "Copy Script" buttons which retrieves data from db, render the new page with data and leads the user to another page.

Comment: You still can execute a form submit off course. You just do it manually. Looking at your answer, that is what you have done anyway so it's all good.

Comment: What surprises me is that DataTable will change the table and prevents the default behaviours... a peculiar corner case I guess.

Comment: DataTables does not change the table. It requires **valid** HTML and a `form` tag cannot be a child of a `table` or `tr` tag as you have coded it. A `form` tag must either be **parent** of the `table` or child of a `td`. In fact the other responder in [the link you included in your answer](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/41804/ie11-issue-with-form-submit-button-within-datatables) stated the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine found a solution: change the `formaction` into `href` and append param after the url, something like what [this question](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/41804/ie11-issue-with-form-submit-button-within-datatables) states, but with details:

Buttons change type to `button` and attached with a `onclick` function:

```
<button type="button" url="{% url 'copyProcess' %}" onClick="copyIE(this,{{proc.id}})" class="btn btn-success btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-clone" title="RELOAD PROCESS"></i></button>
```

The function:

```
function copyIE(elem,indent){

  var url = $(elem).attr("url");
  formManager='#formManager'+indent;
  csrfValue=$("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
  $(formManager).attr("action", url);
  /* get the hidden input's value, construct another input element, and append to the form */
  $('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    id: 'id',
    name: 'id',
    value: indent
  }).appendTo(formManager);

  /* get the csrf token, construct another input element, and append to the form */
  $('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    id: 'csrfmiddlewaretoken',
    name: 'csrfmiddlewaretoken',
    value: csrfValue
  }).appendTo(formManager);

  $(formManager).submit();
}
```

(the line form is named `formManager{{proc.id}}` to distinguish between each row)

Answer (score 0):

You can place your form inside each table data tag like the code below:

```
    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-head-fixed">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Unit Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Accommodation Type</th>
                        <th scope="col">House Keeping</th>
                        <th scope="col">Type ID</th>
                        <th scope="col">Unit ID</th>
                        <th scope="col">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for unit in units %}
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ dates_details.checkindate }}" name="checkindate">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ dates_details.checkoutdate }}" name="checkoutdate">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ dates_details.no_of_nights }}" name="no_of_nights">
                        <tr>
                            <td scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                            <td><input value="{{ unit.unit_name }}" type="hidden"
                                       name="unit_name">{{ unit.unit_name }}</td>
                            <td><input value="{{ unit.accommodation_type_name }}" type="hidden"
                                       name="accommodation_type_name">{{ unit.accommodation_type_name }}
                            </td>
                            <td><input value="{{ unit.house_keeping }}" type="hidden"
                                       name="house_keeping">{{ unit.house_keeping }}</td>
                            <td><input value="{{ unit.accommodation_type_id }}" type="hidden"
                                       name="accommodation_type_id">{{ unit.accommodation_type_id }}
                            </td>
                            <td><input value="{{ unit.id }}" type="hidden"
                                       name="unit_id">{{ unit.id }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <form method="post" action="customer_booking_details">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    <input type="hidden" value="{{ dates_details.checkindate }}" name="checkindate">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="{{ dates_details.checkoutdate }}"
                                           name="checkoutdate">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="{{ dates_details.no_of_nights }}"
                                           name="no_of_nights">
                                    <input value="{{ unit.unit_name }}" type="hidden"
                                           name="unit_name">
                                    <input value="{{ unit.accommodation_type_name }}" type="hidden"
                                           name="accommodation_type_name">
                                    <input value="{{ unit.house_keeping }}" type="hidden"
                                           name="house_keeping">
                                    <input value="{{ unit.accommodation_type_id }}" type="hidden"
                                           name="accommodation_type_id">
                                    <input value="{{ unit.id }}" type="hidden"
                                           name="unit_id">
                                    <button type="submit"
                                            class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm m-1 float-md-left"><i
                                            class="fas fa-step-forward mr-2"></i>SELECT
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% empty %}
                        <div class="alert alert-default-info" role="alert">
                            No Units available at the moment
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```