# dataTables form won't submit correctly in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

**TL;DR** - everything works well enough EXCEPT for getting the cart iframe to refresh at the end. Even `window.location.reload(true);`, which I thought forced a reload of the entire page, doesn't work, but hitting `F5` will.

My question ultimately stems from the same issue presented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49533389/form-submit-button-in-a-datatable-not-working-in-ie-11due-to-datatable-bug). DataTables requires valid HTML so `<form>` must be child of `<td>`. I am trying to find a javascript solution so the forms on each row will work in IE and older Edge that don't support the `form attribute` for inputs outside the `<form>` tags as shown in this representative row of the dataTables (it would normally show 25 at a time):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <form id="101110" name="form" method="post" action="Cart.cfm" target="cart_frame">
                <input name="ItemID" type="hidden" id="ItemID" value="101110">
                <input title="Click to add to cart" name="Submit" type="submit" class="buttons" value="101110">
                <input name="Qty" type="hidden" value="">
                <input name="Brand" type="hidden" value="">
                <input name="Pack" type="hidden" value="113">
                <input name="UOM" type="hidden" value="CS">
            </form>
        </td>
        <td><input form="101110" title="Type number and ENTER to add to cart" name="Qty" type="text" id="Qty" value="" size="1" maxlength="4"></td>
        <td><input form="101110" name="Broken" type="checkbox" id="Broken"></td>
        <td>MY AWESOME WIDGET #115</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>115</td>
        <td>48.50</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>0.52</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have come up with an ugly javascript solution to intercept the submit, find the other 2 inputs and add their data as needed, submit a `XMLHttpRequest` and reload the page. However, even though the correct `responseText` comes back and is sent to the `cart_frame`, the frame shows blank until I hit `F5`. Here is my source:

```
    document.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        // disable the normal form submit handler
        e.preventDefault();
        // store reference to form
        const form = e.target;
        var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var urlEncodedData = "";
        var urlEncodedDataPairs = [];

        // convert form elements into an array of URL-encoded key/value pairs.
        for (var i = 0, element; element = form.elements[i++];) {
            urlEncodedDataPairs.push(encodeURIComponent(element.name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(element.value));
        };
    /*
    *** FIND THE QTY AND BROKEN INPUTS AND ADD TO ABOVE ARRAY
    *** IF TABLE STRUCTURE CHANGES IT WILL BREAK THIS!!!
    */
        // get the NEXT td element of the form's parent node
        var tdSib1 = form.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
        // get child element (Qty)
        var input1 = tdSib1.firstElementChild;
        urlEncodedDataPairs.push(encodeURIComponent(input1.name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(input1.value));
        // get the child of the NEXT td (Broken)
        var input2 = tdSib1.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild;
        //console.log(input2.name  + '=' + input2.checked);
        if (input2.checked) {
            urlEncodedDataPairs.push(encodeURIComponent(input2.name) + '=on');
        }
        // convert array into a single string and replace all %-encoded spaces to 
        // the '+' character; matches the behaviour of browser form submissions.
        urlEncodedData = urlEncodedDataPairs.join('&').replace(/%20/g, '+');
        console.log(urlEncodedData);

        XHR.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
            // success
            if (XHR.readyState === XHR.DONE) {
                if (XHR.status === 200) {
                    var destframe = parent.document.getElementsByName('cart_frame')[0];
                    destframe.src = XHR.responseText;
                    //console.log(XHR.responseText);
                    //destframe.contentWindow.location.reload(true); //did not work either
                    // what do I need to get cart to refresh properly???
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }
            }
        });

        XHR.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
            alert('Oops! Something went wrong.');
        });

        // Set up our request
        XHR.open('POST', form.action);

        // Add the required HTTP header for form data POST requests
        XHR.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        XHR.send(urlEncodedData);
    });
```

How can I force a true refresh of the cart iframe so it shows the updated `responseText`? If it matters for some reason, that iframe is in a **hidden** `<div>` at the time since the cart updates in the background and just displays the updated # of items on a button on the main page that changes which `div` are shown and hidden to show the cart when ready to checkout.

Alternatively, is there is a better way to accomplish submitting a form on a single row of dataTables in IE? I know I can't change the table/form HTML structure and it must be supported in IE 11. I'll be moving my source into its own function so it can also run when hitting Enter in the Qty `input` element.

Comment: Try making a div and pasting the responsetext of the page you want to iframe in a interval.

Comment: @FrV What in place of XmlHttpRequest? And I agree IE is crap. I've never used it personally, but 20% of our customer's clients still do so we must support it.

Comment: I mean, you have an iframe, remove that, make an XmlHttpRequest to the iframe, and set the innerhtml of a div with the responsetext that an interval for the responsetext gives you

Comment: @Sam I'm not a javascript guy so it's not totally clear to me what you are saying so I'll ask some stupid questions. :) By interval are you suggesting I'm not getting the full response even though I'm waiting for 200 status before setting iframe's source? If I remove iframe from DOM, how would I make XmlHttpRequest to the iframe? Here is the current div source for the cart iframe: `<div class="box_c3" id="box_c3"><iframe class="cart_frame" name="cart_frame" src="cart.cfm"></iframe></div>`

Comment: Make a request to cart.cfm, and get the value of it in an interval, lets say 200ms, and then updating it everytime.

Comment: @Sam The request IS to cart.cfm. It sounds like you're suggesting to continuously make requests? That seems pretty wasteful.

Comment: yes but by that youll imitate an iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I wasn't far enough up the DOM. Changing

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

to

```
window.top.location.reload();
```

was all that was needed to reload the whole page. :/

Alternatively, this also worked without having to reload everything so it is what I have chosen to do.

```
destframe.src="cart.cfm";
```